# Upper bound of classification accuracy for psychiatric disorders

Tags: classification

I have the following rather general/open-end question:

Classically, psychiatric disorders like the autism spectrum disorder (ASD) are diagnosed after a complex combination of behavioral assessments and interviews. Recently, more and more researchers are using classification methods from machine learning to try to classify subjects with ASD versus typically developed subjects. 
However, as you can imagine, the labels of the data examples we use stem from the mentioned behavioral assessments, and it is nowhere certain how "objective" such labeling is, also given that autism as an example varies in its expressions (and in the neural markers as well).
Hence it is to be expected that not even theoretically a classification accuracy of 100% can be reached. In fact in this [study](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2213158214001983) they run a classifier on the results of behavioral tests and reach an accuracy of about 95% (classification accuracy on neural data, for instance fMRI scans is at the moment between 70 and 80%).

Question: If I reach a classification accuracy of say 75% on neural data, but the upper benchmark is 95% anyway - should I not adjust my classification accuracy accordingly (increase as a percentage of the 95 for instance)?

(ps: I think this topic is a bit complex anyway, since I assume that "labeling"/diagnosis in this context will always presuppose behavioral assesments, which in turn always lack some objectivity)

Comment: No, don't do that. Referees will otherwise suggest rejection of your paper based on numbers manipulated to appear larger than they actually are. However, do consider other metrics than accuracy. Be sure to report also sensitivity and specificity at least.